# Can I integrate some kind of mapview into a blackberry widget?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-widgets

I would like to create a Blackberry Widget that contains a map view.

Since the whole widget is a web page with java script etc. I think it should be possible to include google maps or something like that into my widget.

Has anybody made experiences with this?

Answer (score 1):

try this

[geo-location-javascript](http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/)

they are providing a JavaScript based geo location for multiple platforms and they are using google map also.

you can check this also
[blackberry.location properties](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11849/blackberry_location_568404_11.jsp)

and you can use [gear apis](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/15286/Support_for_Gears_APIs_738961_11.jsp) also.

Comment: sorry but I know how to use a search engine. All this stuff is only geo location. That means it tells me where the user is but it does not shows a mapview that I can use to add markers to it etc.

Comment: if you download geo-location-javascript.zip, you will find sample file
sample_with_map.html. you can open this file in browser also it will show lat, lon and google map.